# How to alternate 2 LED strings using 555 IC?

Tags: mosfet, 555

I have one sensor that goes on/off at times, I want to flash 2 LED strings (RED, GREEN) every 1 second using a 555 IC.

So when sensor ON
1st second GREEN-ON,RED-OFF
2nd second GREEN-OFF, RED-ON

the 555 IC can sink and source, do I use a P and N channel MOSFETs to drive the LEDS?

Is this schematic correct? have I connected the MOSFETS correctly and also I'm not sure about the 555 timing if it is 1 second ON 1 second OFF

[image]

Can anyone suggest different approach

Please help

Comment: How much current do you require for the red string and for the green string? What voltage are you using to operate the 555 in your schematic? And what voltage is required for each of your LED strings, as well?

Comment: about 2A for LEDs 12V, 555 is TTL voltage (I think)

Comment: Okay. I wanted to be assured that the 555's output was itself inadequate given that it had an adequate supply of its own. The "TTL voltage (I think)" does need clarification, though. What is this connected to?

Comment: Ok, SENSOR is 5V (ill worry about that later if it is not)

Comment: Can you use the +12V rail for the 555? Or does it have to be something much lower, like the +5V you mentioned?

Comment: Are the values swapped on C4/C1? Do you care that duty cycle will be 25% for one LED and 75% for the other?

Comment: I think your setup looks fine, assuming the MOSFET's can handle the current and the duty cycle is not an issue for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can drive the strings like this (555 circuit shown for 50% duty cycle when used with CMOS 555) M1 needs to be a logic-level MOSFET. For 1Hz (0.5s on 0.5s off, R6*C1 needs to be about 0.71, so you could use 1uF and 710K with a CMOS 555.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fIsB4l.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>